# get size of collection in nested hashmap?

Tags: java, collections, hashmap

I have data structure of type `Map<String, Map <String, List<ExciseReportDataPoint>>> Data` I would like to calculate number of entries in `List<ExciseReportDataPoint>` for each top level key.

We can think about the hashmap in logical manner as `Map<LiquorCategory, Map<LiquorBrand, List<LiquorBottles>>>`. Basically I want to know how many liquor bottles for each LiquorCategory.

Comment: You are expected to attempt the code yourself and ask if you encounter a problem. We don't write code for you if you make no attempt yourself.

Comment: I agree how to take down the question?

Comment: map.get(LiquorCategory).size() ?

Comment: @DarshanPuranik vote to close if you are able (not sure what the rep requirement is to VTC).

Comment: There is also a `delete` button below the question's tags.

Comment: I voted to close.

Comment: @DarshanPuranik Just say that you vote to close is even less useful than 'useless'

Comment: @azro I tried to delete it but Stackoverflow doesnt allow. I have voteup for close and flagged for moderator intervention. I have no other way to take down this question.

Comment: @DarshanPuranik it's a bit normal to disable the possibility to delete the question with one vote ... you just don't have to tell us in comment ^^

Answer (score 1):

You have to iterate over the first level `Map`, and then over the second to compute all the `List.size`

**First WAY**

```
Map<String, Map <String, List<Double>>> Data = new HashMap<String, Map <String, List<Double>>> ();
int somme = 0;
for(String key1 : Data.keySet()){
    somme = 0;
    for(List<Double> value2 : Data.get(key1).values()){
        somme += value2.size();
    }
    System.out.println("For "+key1+", there is "+somme+" bottles");
}
```

To use it you have just to change the type of the elements (String, double with Liquor...)

**Second WAY**

```
Data.keySet().stream().forEach(key1 -> {
            System.out.println("For " + key1 + ", there is "
                    + Data.get(key1).values().stream().mapToInt(list -> list.size()).sum() + " bottles");
        });
```

Here you don't have to take care about types, they aren't used, and it does the same in 3 lines
Streams are an alternative to iterate and filter, sum, count ...

Answer (score 1):

Map<String, Map <String, List<Double>>> data = new HashMap<String, Map <String, ArrayList<Double>>> ();

for (Map.Entry<String, HashMap<String, List<Double>>> liquorCategoryEntry : data.entrySet()) {

```
String category = liquorCategoryEntry.getKey();

int liquorBottle = 0;
for (Map.Entry<String, List<Double>> liquorBrandEntry : liquorCategoryEntry.getValue().entrySet()) {
    String brandName = liquorBrandEntry.getKey();
    liquorBottle += liquorBrandEntry.getValue().size();
    // ...
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

I wrote following code based on suggestions based on some answers. This is working for me. The code looks as follows:

```
for (Map.Entry<String, Map<String, List<ExciseReportDataPoint>>> entry1 : rData.entrySet()) {
     int liquorBottle = 0;
     for(List<ExciseReportDataPoint> value2 : rData.get(entry1.getKey()).values()){
         liquorBottle += value2.size();
     }
}
```